# expo ios command exited with error code 65

Tags: react-native, expo, revenuecat

I am trying to use revenueCat on my expo managed workflow project using this [tutorial](https://www-origin.revenuecat.com/blog/expo-in-app-purchase-tutorial/). I am trying to test the project by running `expo run:ios` but I get these bunch of errors. Here is a screenshot -

[image]

```
› 215 error(s), and 1 warning(s)

Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I don't know how else to fix. Can someone help?

Comment: In managed workflow you shouldn’t have an ios folder. Delete the ios folder …

Comment: Running just `expo start` throws this error - Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null. So I read somewhere that I need to run - `expo run:ios`

Comment: Your project seems t have an ios folder which should be deleted

Comment: Importing `react-native-purchases` into my project throws the error - `Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.`

Comment: Are you using Firebase? - I am having same issue and only since i added firebase.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add packages with native code to expo (Excep of [config plugins](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/))

Comment: As you can read here https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/

the module is only available in bare mode.